# Server/Cloud Space for GPS App Startup

Tags: gps, cloud, storage, startup, application-server

If I am starting up a company that provides GPS tracking services for pets to be ran through an app on IOS/Android devices, and I expect to have at least **25,000** customers in the first year, how much server/cloud space would I need to satisfy this need, and around how much would it cost?

Comment: You should use scalable servers. So you can expand it's capacity as users increases.
Amazon AWS would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks Rishi this was very helpful!

Comment: Would you happen be able to guess which specific service from AWS would be the best solution for me scenario? The application would allow for GPS tracking, and allow for push notifications if that helps distinguish a more appropriate package.

Comment: Start with basic micro server...and see it more cloud space is required or not based on your app perfomance. I guess for first 500 users basic AWS micro server would be fine.
Other good options:
Google Cloud Platform
Microsoft Assure

All are scalable. :)